# MongoDB performance: $and vs. single object with multiple keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an internal service that does some operations on an order, it has a built-in required filter, and the service users can pass additional filter.

Two approaches to achieve the same thing:
A) Using `$and`:

```js
async function getOrders ({ optionalFilter = {} }) {
  const baseFilter = { amount: { $gt: 10 } };
  const mergedFilter = { $and: [baseFilter, optionalFilter] };

  return await Order.find(mergedFilter);
}
```

B) Merging all in the same object

```js
async function getOrders ({ optionalFilter = {} }) {
  const baseFilter = { amount: { $gt: 10 } };
  const mergedFilter = { ...baseFilter, ...optionalFilter };

  return await Order.find(mergedFilter);
}
```

I prefer the first approach because it allows me to do the following without overwriting the `$gt: 10` rule while the second would break the code by overwriting the internal rule.

```js
getOrders({ optionalFilter: { amount: { $lt: 50 } } });
```

My question is, is there any advantage (performance or otherwise) of choosing one over the other?

Comment: if my answer was helpful, could you please mark it as accepted or at least upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there any advantage (performance or otherwise) of choosing one over the other?

- Short answer: No. If you are not using (compound) indexes
- Long Answer: Okay, let's test this up, right?

So let's take a collection of ~100k documents, and un-indexed array field:

1. `{asset_class: "COMMDTY"}`
   [image: unIndexed]
2. with `{$and: [{item_subclass: "Herb", asset_class: "COMMDTY"}]}`
   [image: and twoFields unIndexed]
3. without `{item_subclass: "Herb", asset_class: "COMMDTY"}`
   [image: twoFields unIndexed]

> Okay, there is `114ms` difference between using `$and` and without. But does it means to stop you using `$and` and avoid it? Of course, not. But as much field have added, the more slower Mongo will become. But this whole picture changes, when I add an already indexed field to a query.

`{expansion: "BFA", asset_class: "COMMDTY"}`
[image: indexed two]

So, if you add more fields via your `mergedFilter` then make sure that your index (if you are using them) can be used, because as for compound index field order is very meaningful. So the query: `{asset_class: "COMMDTY", expansion: "BFA" }` will goes already in:
[image: 11ms]